# Hello World node.js for Azure not working

Tags: node.js, powershell, azure, azure-sdk-.net

I've tried to follow [this very basic introduction to Node.js, Azure and the Azure SDK for Node.js](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/getting-started/)

All is going according to plan, until I get to this:

```
PS C:\node\helloworld\WebRole1> Start-AzureEmulator -Launch

Creating local package...
Starting Emulator...
Start-AzureEmulator : The system cannot find the file specified
At line:1 char:20
+ Start-AzureEmulator <<<<  -Launch
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Start-AzureEmulator], Win32Exce
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AzureDeploymentCmdlets.Cmdlet.StartAzureEmulator
   Command
```

I'm new to Node.js and invoking the emulator from PowerShell, so I don't really know where to go from there to figure out what might be wrong. I haven't been able to find this exact error on Google, so I'm a bit stuck.

Any ideas where to go from here? Are there any logs anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to test it on my machine and see the emulator starting up, so it looks like an install issue with the Windows Azure SDK.
Can you make sure the SDK is installed properly from "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254279&clcid=0x409".
◦Install the Windows Azure SDK for Node.js: Windows installer

If this doesn't help, a procmon log might give insight into the missing files.
"http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645"

Comment: I've got the SDK installed from the link you gave - this is part of the tutorial. Will try to get procmon log...

Comment: Thanks for your procmon tip. See my note on the Pats post.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a 'node' issue per se.  The error refers to the local compute emulator not being found by the PS script.

You should have a directory with the emulator @
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Emulator

You can also do a search for the emulator by going to the Search box in the Start Menu (Win7) or the Search feature of Win8 (right swipe).  Just search for the key word 'emulator'

If the directory doesn't exist or is empty, it probably means the Azure SDK is not fully installed.

If the emulator is configured correctly, but you don't have the webrole setup, you would get a different error.  Something like:
Start-AzureEmulator : service definition (*.csdef) file is invalid or empty

Pat

Comment: I've got both c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure and c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure. I've also developed .Net application using the Azure emulator... I find both Compute Emulator and Storage Emulator when searching in Windows.

Comment: I did have the emulator where you said it should be, but it seems that's not where it's looking for it. Using procmon, I see it's actually looking here: C:\Program Files\Windows Azure Emulator\emulator - I tried copying it to that location, and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have [Windows Azure SDK v1.8](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35448) installed